# Why does this function not update my storage array?

Tags: storage, arrays, memory

Since reference types such as arrays are passed by reference by in Solidity, they pass a reference (pointer) to the value. Any change to that value will reflect on original value.

If this is the case, why the `changeVar()` function does not change the value of marks array?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract ref {
     uint[] public marks  = [1,2,33];

    function changeVar() public {
        changeVal(marks);
    }

    function changeVal(uint[] memory _uint) public returns(uint[] memory){
            _uint[0] = 111;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You added the `memory` modifier to the `_uint` argument. That means that whatever value you pass to the `changeVal` function, the array will be worked on in memory, not in storage.

So to answer your point, this is indeed a reference, but it's a reference to an array saved in memory. If you'd like to operate on and modify the storage array, you'd want to change the modifier to `storage`.

You may benefit from reading the [Layout in Memory](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/internals/layout_in_memory.html) section of the Solidity docs.

Comment: Thanks but it gives error whenever I pass storage as an argument.

Comment: Whenever I pass storage as an argument, it says either calldata or memory needed but storage passed.

Comment: If my answer helped you, don't forget that you can click the thumbs up button, or mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have responded my question. It took storage as an argument...

Answer (score 0):

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0; 

contract ref { 

uint[] public marks  = [1,2,33]; 

function changeVar() external { 
    changeVal(marks); 
} 

function changeVal(uint[] storage _uint) internal{ 
    _uint[0] = 111; 
    } 
}
```

The only way to pass the storage keyword to the function argument is if its type is `internal` or `private.` The functions will receive a copy when called by a regular user from another contract regardless of its type (reference or value). For other cases where pass by reference is used, see the [examples](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html#reference-types).